# Ergodic properties of a subsquence of an ergodic diffusion process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, ergodic-theory

Let $X_t$ be an ergodic diffusion process with invariant measure $\mu(dx)$ on $I$ and  satisfying, say for bounded $f$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0f(X_t)dt= \int_If(x)\mu(dx)
\end{equation}
Let $t_k, k=1,2,\ldots$ be as subsequence $0\leq t_k \rightarrow \infty$.  What conditions on the $t_k$ are necessary  for
\begin{equation}
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n_T}\sum_{k=0}^{n_T}f(X_{
t_k})=\int_If(x)\mu(dx)
\end{equation}
where $n_T=\#\{t_k\leq T\}$?